# Using and Posting results of Sortable in Django

Tags: jquery, django, jquery-ui, django-views

I am making a list of models that I want to be able to drag around, then save the order as their new ordering in the database based off a ordering value attached.
Right now I have this code for the html:

```
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/3.2.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'draggable.js' %}"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#test").submit(function(event){

        $.ajax({
             type:"POST",
             url:"{% url 'editpage' bid=book.id pid=page.page_num %}",
             data: {
                    'order': 1 // insert ordering here
                    },
             success: function(){
             }
        });
        return false;
   });
});

</script>
</head>

<body>


<h1>{{page.page_title}}</h1>
<ul id="sortable">
    {% for section in sections.all %}
        <li style="background:blue">{{section.section_title}}</li>
    {% endfor %}

</ul>
<form method='post' id ='test'>
    <input type='submit' value='Test button'/>
</form>
```

The problem I am having is trying to get sortable to work. Where do I insert the script `(#sortable).sortable()` so that it will work when the page loads and then on press, POST to the view for parsing.

My view if it helps:

```
@ensure_csrf_cookie
def editpage(request, bid = -1, pid = 1):
    ret = {}
    b = Textbook.objects.get(id = int(bid))
    page = b.pages.get(page_num = int(pid))
ret = {

    'book':b,
    'page':page,
    'sections':page.sections,
}
if request.method == 'POST':
    print(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>" + request.POST.get('order'))

return render(request,"content/editpage.html", ret)
```

A good part of this is test code but I am trying to get it to work on a small scale before full implementation. The two major questions I have are where do I insert the sortable code and how do I save that info to POST on button press.

Comment: Don't you just place it inside onload function for it to work when the page loads? And what do you want to send to your view? And what do you want to do with it in your view?

Comment: There's a number of ways to do this. If you want to ensure that it loads after all other elements, you could add a `<script>` section at the end of the page. You can also use `onload`, `$(document).ready(function(){})`, or more commonly used now, `$(function(){});` in your JavaScript head portion.

Comment: Also, jQuery has version 3.2.1 yet jQuery UI is only up to version 1.12.1. So that call to ui 3.2.1 will fail. Please review: https://code.jquery.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of the JavaScript that you can use.

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/h15mv6cr/

**HTML**

```
<h1>Page Title</h1>
<ul id="sortable">
  <li style="background:blue" id="model-1">Section Title 1</li>
  <li style="background:blue" id="model-2">Section Title 2</li>
  <li style="background:blue" id="model-3">Section Title 3</li>
  <li style="background:blue" id="model-4">Section Title 4</li>
  <li style="background:blue" id="model-5">Section Title 5</li>
</ul>
<a id="test" href="#">Test Button</a>
```

**CSS**

```
#sortable {
  margin: 1px;
  border: 1px solid #EEE;
  padding: 2px;
  list-style: none;
  width: 210px;
  background: #FFF;
}

#sortable li {
  padding: 3px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  margin: 2px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  $("#test").button().click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var serialOrder = $("#sortable").sortable("serialize");
    var arrayOrder = $("#sortable").sortable("toArray");
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      // used for this example
      url: "/echo/json/",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
        json: JSON.stringify(arrayOrder)
      },
      success: function(data) {
        // Do something with the data
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
  });
  $("#sortable").sortable();
});
```

Your code will be different. This is just a close example based on what might be populated in your page.

You had nothing in your form that would collect the order or data from the sortable list. this is done using either the `serialize` or `toArray` methods. See more: http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/

Hope that helps.

Comment: When using your javascript I get crsf errors and the list still is not draggable. I just replaced my js with yours then changed it to match my vars. Do I need to import or include a file in order to make it work?

Comment: Did you see my comment regarding your jQuery UI 3.2.1 call? That file does not exists. Make sure you're using the correct URL: https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js

Comment: I see and I fixed that. No more errors and all is working but the post actions are not occurring in my terminal. Buttons function but don't execute.

Comment: Don't use my exact AJAX code. You'll want to set that back to your needs. Depending on your browser, you will see the AJAX details under the Network section of your console.

Comment: For example, the `data` should be like: `data: serialOrder` so that you post an array of data in the proper method. The AJAX in my example was specific to jsfiddles AJAX Echo features.

Comment: the problem I am getting is that the sortable array or serialize  are null or empty. I think it has to do with itemizing my <li> tags but I do not know how to do that dynamically (this list is not fixed sized and loaded from a db). The models have a order value but it is not working in the class of the li tag.

Comment: They require a ID Attribute. See the HTML portion, where `id="model-1"` etc in my example.

Comment: Also, you can leverage more features of the UI: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/h15mv6cr/2/